# Talend - Process large delimited file

Tags: csv, talend

i've got a questions regarding on how to process a delimited file with a large number of columns (>3000).
I tried to extract the fields with the standard delimited file input component, but creating the schema takes hours and when i run the job i get an error, because the toString() method exceeds the 65535 bytes limit. At that point i can run the job but all the columns are messed up and i cant realy work with them anymore.

Is it possible to split that .csv-file with talend? Is there any other handling possible, maybe with some sort of java code? If you have any further questions dont hesitate to comment.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You can create the schema of the delimited file in Metadata right? I tested 3k columns with some millions of records and it did not even take 5 minutes to load all the column names with data types. Obviously you can't split that file by taking each row as one cell, it could exceed the limit of strings in talend. But you can do it in Java using **BufferedReader**.

Answer (score 0):

To deal with Big delimited file, we need something designed for big data, I think it will be a good choice to load your file to a MongoDB collection using this command with no need to create a 3k columns collection before importing file:

```
mongoimport --db users --collection contacts --type csv --headerline --file /opt/backups/contacts.csv
```

After that, you can process your data easily using an ETL tool.

See [MongoImprort Ref](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/#csv-import).

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Im not even able to open the file via Excel. I get an out of memory error. Excel just dont get over 1.6 gb used memory and there is lots of free memory but he always crashs :/

Comment: Edited answer, because Oracle have limited columns number, i suggest to use MongoDB.

Comment: I also thought about that kind of processing. Im using an Exasol DB and there i have to define the table with all the columns before i can transfer it. Thats why i was looking for some kind of solution that uses talend or java components in talend

Comment: This is why i suggested Mongo db, because you can load data without creating the table previously, it will use the first line of the file as header for column names `--headerline`.

Comment: Yeah i just saw it in your line of code, big thanks for that. Maybe it wont work in that case because some of the headlines consist of "<" or ">". But nevermind, thanks for your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could have a go with [uniVocity](http://www.univocity.com/pages/univocity-tutorial). It is built to handle all sorts of extreme situations processing data.

Check out the [tutorial](http://www.univocity.com/pages/univocity-tutorial#auto-detection-and-other-useful-capabilities) and see if suits your needs.

Here's a simple project which works with CSV inputs: https://github.com/uniVocity/worldcities-import/

Disclosure: I am the author of this library. It's open-source and free (Apache V2.0 license).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but my answer was focused more on how could i achive it with talend or any kind of development within talend. I dont know if i'm albe to integrate uniVocity in talend. Do you have any experience with that?